# How do I make sure the Tween values doesn't make a huge jump?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm implementing animations in my app. When the screen loads, I want to make the container come from bottom to the middle of the screen, gradually increasing in height and width.
But the width jumps from 0 to 356:

code in initState:

```
width = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 400.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.ease
      ),
    );
height = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 400.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.ease
      ),
    );
padding = EdgeInsetsTween(
      begin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
      end: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100.0),
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.ease
      ),
    );
```

code:

```
late final AnimationController _animationController2 = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
    vsync: this,
  );

AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: _animationController2,
    builder: (context, child) { 
    print("width: ${width.value}");
    return Container(
      padding: padding.value,
      width: width.value,
      height: height.value,
      child: Container());
     }
  )
```

debug output:

```
flutter: width: 0.0
flutter: width: 356.16800278425217
flutter: width: 357.25352596491575
flutter: width: 358.32799911499023
flutter: width: 359.0381249785423
flutter: width: 359.74326372146606
flutter: width: 360.4433849453926
flutter: width: 361.48409243673086
flutter: width: 362.17153687030077
flutter: width: 363.19308668375015
flutter: width: 363.8676643371582
flutter: width: 364.53704208135605
flutter: width: 365.20118951797485
flutter: width: 366.18753734976053
flutter: width: 366.8384760245681
```

What I want to achieve is a small step wise increase in tween values!
desired output:

```
width: 0,
width: 20,
width: 40,
width: 60,
...
```

It's the same for height and padding. How should I implement it?

Comment: `animation: _animationController` maybe?

Comment: I have two animations going on... I edited my question @pskink

Comment: but your `AnimatefBuilder` is driven only by one

Comment: I have this going on: the first animation is for the logo. After it is completed, I have this animation, which contains login and signup buttons...

Comment: `width`, `height` and `padding` are driven by `_animationController` and not `_animationController2` (see what you are passing to `animate` method)

Comment: oh thanks, took a while to notice that  @pskink

Comment: If you can please post that comment as an answer, I'll mark that answer as accepted because that was the real solution to my question @pskink

Comment: feel free to post a self answer then :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) mentioned in the comments,

As per my code, I had to change from `_animationController` to `_animationController2`.
From:

```
width = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 400.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.ease
      ),
    );
```

to this:

```
width = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 400.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController2,
        curve: Curves.ease
      ),
    );
```

for all: width, height and padding.